# Можно ли как-то пометить определенную дату в Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Запускаем новый сайт: и дизайн, и функционал.
Хотелось бы в Google Analytics каким-то образом иметь возможность сравнивать статистику до и после обновлений.

Какие есть варианты?

Я думал может быть там есть возможность пометить определенную дату, и она на всех графиках будет как-то отобраджаться?
Может быть есть какая-то сегментация?

Comment: Добавить метку к дате можно, под графиком раскрывается панелька. Точно не помню - поэтому как комментарий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел!
Оставлю ответ тем, кому это может пригодиться...

Google это называет "аннотация".
Будучи в Analytics надо:

- зайти в `Admin`
- указать `Account` -> `Property` -> `View` и нажать `Annotations`
- нажать `Create New Annotation`. Указать дату и дать описание.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И тогда на графика появится меточка в указанной дате.
При нажатии на метку появится описание...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В обзоре аудитории, там, где выбирается диапазон дат, можно поставить галку "Сравнить с" и выбрать диапазон дат для сравнения, тогда на графике будет будут отображаться две кривые, за два диапазона дат.

Comment: да, это как вариант. Но не совсем подходит. Идеально было бы если бы он сам помнил дату, а не мне приходилось выбирать.. Потом, у нас много пользователей на аккаунте. Я дату знаю, а они - нет... Хотелось бы, чтобы GA показывал дату каким-то способом...